# How to prove $\frac{y^2-x^2}{x+y+1}=\pm1$ is a hyperbola?

Tags: analytic-geometry

How to prove $\frac{y^2-x^2}{x+y+1}=\pm1$ is a hyperbola, knowing the canonical form is $\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=\pm1$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants? Thanks !

Comment: I think analytic geometry or conic sections is a better tag . Hyperbola does not necessarily imply hyperbolic geometry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the '+' sign, $$y^2-x^2=x+y+1\implies\left(y-\frac12\right)^2-\left(x+\frac12\right)^2=1^2$$

$$\implies\frac{\left(y-\frac12\right)^2}{1^2}-\frac{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2}{1^2}=1^2$$

Similarly for the '-' sign,

$$y^2-x^2=-(x+y+1)\implies\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\left(y+\frac12\right)^2=1^2$$

Can you recognize $a,b$ here?

Comment: I trully appreciate your reply, but hardly see how this helps since, no, I can't recognize $a$ and $b$...

Comment: @user111288, how about the edited version? See also, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularHyperbola.html

Comment: Trying as hard as I can to, but no...! One more edit, maybe? :P! Edit : Ha, okay, wait a second, looking at that Wolfram link !

Comment: @user111288 If the center of the hyperbola is at $(h,k)$ then the "canonical form" is $(y-k)^2/a^2 -(x-h)^2/b^2=\pm 1$. [Usually I've seen the $a$ associated to the $x$ term and the $b$ to the $y$ term, however.] To put this another way, the "canonical form" may be for a different coordinate system than that of the originally given conic, which means if originally one has an equation in $x,y$ one might need new variables $u,v$ for the "standard form". This is especially true if a rotation is needed.

Comment: Hah ! THANK YOU very much ! The hyperbola isn't centered at (0,0) !

Comment: @user111288, As the transformation of axes does not change the nature of a curve, we can set $y-\frac12=Y,x+\frac12=X$ in the first case

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
\frac{y^2-x^2}{x+y+1}=1\\
\Rightarrow y^2-x^2=x+y+1\\
\Rightarrow y^2-x^2-x-y=1
$$
Complete the squares for x and y . You will get  rectangular hyperbola. Similar will be the case if
$$
\frac{y^2-x^2}{x+y+1}=-1$$